# Processor or RAM?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, processor

I want to buy a macbook pro in the near future, but choosing the configuration has been a headache for me so far. My options are :

Macbook Pro 13" Retina
2.9GHz Dual-core Intel **Core i5**, Turbo Boost up to 3.3GHz
**16GB** 1866MHz LPDDR3 SDRAM 
**128GB** PCIe-based Flash Storage

Or

Macbook Pro 13" Retina
3.1GHz Dual-core Intel **Core i7**, Turbo Boost up to 3.4GHz
**8GB** 1866MHz LPDDR3 SDRAM 
**128GB** PCIe-based Flash Storage

Or

MacBook Pro 13" (non-retina)
2.9GHz Dual-core Intel **Core i7**, Turbo Boost up to 3.6GHz
**8GB** 1600MHz DDR3 SDRAM — 2x4GB
**500GB** Serial ATA Drive @ 5400 rpm

I do photo editing quiet a lot. That's the reason i want to change my current laptop since its slow for editing photos and maybe sometimes playing some games. If you can help me decide i would really appreciate it. 
Thanks

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't suggest using a mac to play games - it isn't known for games. You should use Windows on a VM or bootcamp.

Comment: Is a cost a factor? Are you reluctant to get a certain model due to its price? If not I would suggest both more RAM and better CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: This may be a bit opinionated due to the nature of this question, and I'll mostly focus on photo editing.)

From what I have seen, (at least on Photoshop) RAM and SSDs are the most important. There have been [people who have run on i5s and get by just as well.](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2808915/6600k-versus-6700k-photoshop.html)

If you can avoid it, don't get the Non-Retina (i.e. get the Retina) especially because you are doing photo editing and it always helps to have a higher resolution while editing so that higher resolution pictures can be used. Also, the drive is not a SSD so it will run slower.

I would recommend getting the first option as you have said:

> Mac[B]ook Pro 13" Retina 2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 3.3GHz 16GB 1866MHz LPDDR3 SDRAM 128GB PCIe-based Flash Storage

simply because of the following reasons (as opposed to the second option that has the i7):

1. The clock speeds are roughly the same (0.2GHz w/o Turbo Boost, 0.1GHz with)
2. Having multiple threads (all i7s have hyperthreading which doubles the amount of threads) [only helps in certain tasks](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1358970).
3. The two above reasons (in my opinion) do not justify adding USD$200 to the price, [while the 16GB of RAM will help](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-much-ram-does-your-pc-need-probably-less-than-you-think/), even though it is USD$80 more than the first option.

For gaming: get the second option. More threads will improve gaming performance and all i7s have hyper-threading. The i7 also has a faster clock speed.

And if it is possible, you may want to just get the faster CPU and the larger RAM, since you want to both game and photo edit.